# Walking behind a woman if you can't see her

Tags: women, parashat-bereishit, tznius-modesty, adam

The [gemara](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=18b&format=pdf) in עירובין יח has a very interesting discussion, it wants to know according to the מ"ד that אדם and חוה were created together back-to-back שני פרצופים, who walked first (i.e. which direction)?

And the gemara answers that

> אמר רב נחמן בר יצחק מסתברא דזכר סגי ברישא דתניא לא יהלך אדם אחורי אשה בדרך ואפי' היא אשתו
>
> Rav Nachman says it seems likely that Adam went first as we learnt that a man should not walk behind a woman even if she's his wife (loose translation).

Most מפרשים understand the reason being tznius (look [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37032&hilite=45d4a584-aa68-4418-811a-b331e92192c8&st=%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%94&pgnum=134)) as is the פשטות of the גמרא (look at the continuation), רש"י though gives a different reason (משום גנאי) regarding walking after ones own wife, (but look [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51922&hilite=3370699a-04b1-4cfd-8cd3-e8f0c19f92ca&st=%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%94) (I don't see the main source on hebrew books, but this sefer quotes it) that even רש"י agrees that the main point is tznius (הרהור), but by ones wife were there is no real tznius issues it's just חשד since others might not know they're a couple).

So the question is since if חוה would be going first אדם would be walking backwards (and he can't see her) wouldn't that negate any problems? Do we see from here that it's אסור להלוך אחורי אשה ואפי' אשתו even if you can't see her???

Comment: But Adam would know Chava was there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is posed by the [Maharsha in Berachos 61A](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.61a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ואפשר שדקדק לומר דהכא משום איסורא לא שייך דמשמע ליה דב' הפרצופין היו כ"א מהם פניו הפך של פנים השני דמש"ה פריך למ"ד פרצוף הי מינייהו מסגי ברישא כיון דכ"א מהם היה פניו הפך השני מי יכריע ביניהם שילך בראש וא"כ זה הולך למזרח וזה למערב וה"ל חמר גמל שא"א להם לזוז ממקומם וא"כ הוא גם אם תלך הנקבה בראש לא יסתכל בה שהרי פניו לצד השני אבל משום גנאי ניחא דיש לזכר לילך בראש ובהכי ניחא שפירש"י בסמוך נזדמנה לו על הגשר אשת איש והיא לפניו עכ"ל שהכריחו לפרש דקאי על א"א ולא אפילו על אשתו דבסמוך לו דבאשתו כיון דאינו אלא משום גנאי אין סברא להטריחו ולסלקה לצדדין ולעבור לפניה אלא דאיירי בא"א דאיסורא נמי אית ביה

In essence he is saying that it is obvious from this Gemara that there is another issue besides Tzniyus, specifically an issue of Derech Eretz and Genai, that is a problem.

Furthermore, the Radvaz (quoted in one of the links in the question) says that in the event that one is on the way for a mitzvah and cannot avoid such a situation, he may keep his eyes to the ground and not look. The [Pitchei Teshuva](https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.21.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) (Even Haezer 21:1) says, based on this Maharsha, that it would only be in a case of a mitzvah, since there is really a separate issue of Derech Eretz/Genai not related to tzniyus at all:

> להלך אחריה. עבה"ט ומ"ש בשם הרדב"ז הוא בח"ב סי' תש"ע. (ושם מסיים אלא ימהר לעבור לפניה אפי' שיעבור תוך ד' אמותיה או יסתלק לצדדין או יאנוס עצמו ויתעכב עד שתלך מלפניו כו' ואם אי אפשר באחד מכל אלה והוא ממהר לדבר מצוה ואם יתעכב יעבור זמן המצוה יתקע עיניו בקרקע וילך ולא יגביהם מן הקרקע ע"ש. ומשמע דתקנתא זו דיתקע עיניו בקרקע לא מהניא אלא דוקא בממהר לדבר מצוה וע' בגמ' ברכות ס"א ולמ"ד פרצוף הי מנייהו סגי ברישא אמר רנב"י מסתברא כו' דתניא כו' וע' במהרש"א

Comment: I don't see the connection between the Radvaz and Maharsha. It seems like a typo in the Pischei Teshuva- probably a missing end parentheses.

Comment: The Radvaz says that looking downward and avoiding your gaze is good enough in a situation where there’s no other option AND your on your way to doing a mitzvah, so not going is not an option. The obvious question would be, why isn’t this an option all the time? Just don’t look. So, while there might be some who explain that it’s because you might look inadvertently, Pischei Teshuva is explaining that it’s because of the inherent Genai that the Maharsha talks about, which is only suspended in this extreme case

Comment: The reason just not looking is not an option is because putting yourself in a position where you might look is worse than actually looking (Bava Basra 57b). The Radvaz is mechadesh that for a mitzva it is ok to just not look. And the Maharsha's reasoning of g'nai should only apply if one is actually following the woman, as in his case or Manoach's, not if he happens to be behind her on the road.